# VPN not reconnect with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client

Tags: vpn, cisco

I try to connect other server by vpn with Cisco AnyConnect. For the first time, it connects. But if I try to reconnect, it shows:

[image]

Okay, but connection has been established for the first time. I perform this in terminal:

```
v-chernyshov@v-chernyshov:~$ nslookup connect.####.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find connect.okmarket.ru: SERVFAIL
```

And I don't understand, what is 127.0.0.53, it not looks like correct server IP.

Please, tell me, what to do.

Comment: 127.0.0.53 is an indicator of SystemD's `resolved` being the one that hands off DNS requests to third party servers.  The "servfail" issue you are seeing is that *something* between you and the Internet, the actual DNS servers, is returning a "failed" lookup.  You may need to restart your networking since your VPN died off, and the actual DNS server(s) in use by AnyConnect are no longer reachable (which explains the SERVFAIL).  Which may mean you need to 'restart' your computer/session in this case, which is the 'easy' way to reset that issue.